# Creating a new thread for a method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, linq

I am currently trying to increase the **Stack** size for a new **Thread**, so that I can run my method below without the application throwing out a ***StackOverflowException***.

```
public QuoteResult CalculateRates(TruckDb db, QuoteData data)
{
    var result = new QuoteResult
    {
        Successful = false,
        Data = data
    };

    //...EDIT with code samples

        //Floor - 1
        var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
        {
            SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
            StockItem = quoteItem.FloorSpec.Name == "Ali Floor Bakery" || quoteItem.FloorSpec.Name == "Trailer Floor" || quoteItem.FloorSpec.Name == "Use Existing Floor" ? null : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated Meat Hanger" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First()
                : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" ||
                quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Tautliner" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Penta Slider Curtain-side" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Bakery Light Weight GRP" ||
                quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Free Flow Bakery Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Boardside GRP Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Drop Side" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Flat Deck" ? quoteItem.ChassisModel.Longitudinal : null
        };
        qisg.Quantity = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : 2;
        qisg.Length = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Round((quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Smooth Folded" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Bakery Light Weight GRP" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Free Flow Bakery Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Boardside GRP Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated Meat Hanger" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Drop Side" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Flat Deck" ? -0.157
            : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Penta Slider Curtain-side" ? -0.150 : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Tautliner" ? -0.060
            : 0) + (quoteItem.ExternalLength / 1000), 3);
        qisg.Weight = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.Mass, 3);
        qisg.Cost = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.UnitCost, 2);
        if (qisg.StockItem != null)
            quoteItem.SectionGroups.Add(qisg);

        //Floor - 2
        qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
        {
            SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Cross Member" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
            StockItem = quoteItem.FloorSpec.Name == "Ali Floor Bakery" || quoteItem.FloorSpec.Name == "Trailer Floor" || quoteItem.FloorSpec.Name == "Use Existing Floor" ? null : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated Meat Hanger" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Penta Slider Curtain-side" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First()
                : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Tautliner" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Bakery Light Weight GRP" ||
                quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Free Flow Bakery Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Boardside GRP Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Drop Side" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Flat Deck" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH075").First() : null
        };
        qisg.Quantity = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Floor(quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated Meat Hanger" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated"
            || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Tautliner"
            || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Bakery Light Weight GRP" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Free Flow Bakery Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Boardside GRP Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Drop Side" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Flat Deck" ? ((quoteItem.ExternalLength / quoteItem.FloorChannelSpacing.Amount) + 2) 
            : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Penta Slider Curtain-side" ? (quoteItem.ExternalLength / quoteItem.FloorChannelSpacing.Amount) : 0);
        qisg.Length = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Round((quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Smooth Folded" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Bakery Light Weight GRP" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Free Flow Bakery Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Boardside GRP Body" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated Meat Hanger" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Drop Side" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Flat Deck" ? -0.020
            : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Penta Slider Curtain-side" ? -0.070 : quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Tautliner" ? -0.030
            : 0) + (quoteItem.ExternalWidth / 1000), 3);
        qisg.Weight = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.Mass, 3);
        qisg.Cost = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.UnitCost, 2);
        if (qisg.StockItem != null)
            quoteItem.SectionGroups.Add(qisg);   

    //It continues on like this with about 80 more blocks of code like the above samples          

    result.Successful = true;
    return result;
}
```

I've tried coding in a couple of ways that people have suggested in other questions, but I cannot figure out how to use my method in a new thread.

Here is one of my tries:

```
void NewThread(QuoteResult result)
{
    const int stackSize = 0x400000;
    var T = new Thread(CalculateRates, stackSize);
    T.Start();
    T.Join();
}
```

But, it throws out the error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart,
>   int)' has some invalid arguments

As you can clearly see, I have NO clue what I am doing or how to create a new thread for my method, so I do expect a lot of criticism. If anyone needs any more code samples or information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks for any help in advance!

And sorry if it's a vague question

**EDIT**

Methods that also use the *CalculateRates* method:

```
public QuoteResult GetQuote(QuoteData Data)
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var result = CalculateRates(db, Data);
        return result;
    }
}
```

AND

```
    public bool FinalizeQuote(QuoteResult quoteResult)
    {
        using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
        {
            var calcResult = CalculateRates(db, quoteResult.Data);

            //Make sure that result still gives the same amount and that they where successful calculations
            if (calcResult.TotalAmount != quoteResult.TotalAmount || !quoteResult.Successful || !calcResult.Successful)
                return false;

            var company = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name == "Test Co.").FirstOrDefault();
            if (company == null)
                company = db.Companies.Add(new Company { Name = "Test Co." });

            var rep = company.Represetatives.Where(x => x.Name == "Person").FirstOrDefault();
            if (rep == null)
            {
                rep = new Represetative { Name = "Person" };
                company.Represetatives.Add(rep);
            }
            var quote = new Quote { Date = DateTime.Now, QuoteNumber = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            rep.Quotes.Add(quote);

            quote.Items.Add(calcResult.QuoteItem);


            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Having a `StackOverflowException` may indicate that you should have another thought about your solution. Can you show us some code?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes I will update soon :)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I've added the code samples

Comment: I don't think the code you provided, will raise a `StackOverflowException`. I don't see recursion. Is `CalculateRates` called enywhere within the method?

Comment: It's called twice with two different methods. I will update the coding. See the EDIT

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I've updated the code again

Comment: `var calcResult = CalculateRates(db, quoteResult.Data);` Are you recalculating the same results? Still can't see recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing in the parameters `CalculateRates` needs.

You can do this by passing in a simple lambda expression:

```
void NewThread(QuoteResult result)
{
    //example for creating the parameters to pass in
    TruckDb db = new TruckDb();
    QuoteData data = new QuoteData();

    const int stackSize = 0x400000;
    var T = new Thread(() => CalculateRates(db, data), stackSize);
    T.Start();
    T.Join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It makes sense of what you are saying, except that I get the error: 'The name 'db' does not exist in the current context'. The same with 'data' :(

Comment: This is because you need to get the parameters from somewhere. You need to know what you pass in

Comment: I edited the code to include example parameters (which will most likely be not what  you want). Just to demonstrate what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Task`

refer the mentioned link [Task](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845634/Multithreading-using-Task-Factory-Csharp-Basic-Sam)

Answer (score 0):

other than what the guys above said already, but you are having a simple syntax error.

You are not passing in the parameters for the Thread method "CalculateRates".
The Thread method should have only one parameter of type "object" which you can pass in, like

```
var t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(youmethod);
t.Start(yourparam);
```

The other solution would be to use closures. But in general, you are simply not passing in the parameters for the method you are trying to call.

check the samples from the MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx